# How do I configure several urls into @FeignClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

- I have this **application.propeties**

```sh
service.path=http://localhost:8000

forex.service.name=forex-service
```

- I have a configured : "FeignClient"

```java
@FeignClient(name="${forex.service.name}", url="${service.path}")
public interface CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy {


  @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
  CurrencyConversionBean retrieveExchangeValue(
          @PathVariable("from") String from, @PathVariable("to") String to);
```

I would like to set multiple URLS. For example, if one of them is not available, then "FeignClient" must go to another one.

Who has any ideas how to do this?

Comment: have you considered the service-discovery for this use case?

Comment: It will be later. maybe. I don't know how will be work Eureka on weblogic. So I consider the variant have described above.

Comment: Probably you should have to define 2 feign clients then and in the client code you have to write if-else to handle the case.. not sure if it's good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I decided the problem so:

- In the all microservices need remove dependencies **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client** (I don't use name server for discovering clients).

  - Remove an annotation **@EnableDiscoveryClient**. In my case this annotation don't need.
  - On a microservice that is intermediary between client requests and another microservices, you need to defined:
  - application.properties

```sql
forex.service.name=forex-service

forex-service.ribbon.listOfServers=localhost:8000,localhost:8001,localhost:8002
```

Certainly you must create services on specified urls and run theirs.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
              </dependency>
```

- proxy for Feign clients

```java
@FeignClient(name="${forex.service.name}")
@RibbonClient(name="${forex.service.name}")
public interface CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy {

  @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
  CurrencyConversionBean retrieveExchangeValue(
          @PathVariable("from") String from, @PathVariable("to") String to);
```

This work only when you use embedded Tomcat (Srping boot 2.2.7).

If you define external server (for example, Weblogic), that your request will try out to forwarded on that. But you will get errors.